# Substition for glTexImage1D in OpenGL es 3.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to port the OpenGL code into OpenGL ES 3.0 code on Android.
However, the function "glTexImage1D" and "GL_TEXTURE_1D" are not defined in
OpenGL ES 2.0 specification. Is there any substitute for that?

My Android phone support 16 texture units, and the implementation of GLSL shader on a personal computer needs to loop-up via 1D texture.

Therefore, the most possible way is to substitute with "glTexImage2D" and  "GL_TEXTURE_2D" ?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void init()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //
    unsigned char buf[32 * 4];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i += 4)
    {
        buf[i + 0] = rand() % 255;
        buf[i + 1] = rand() % 255;
        buf[i + 2] = rand() % 255;
        buf[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 4, sizeof(buf) / 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
    glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);

    glLineWidth(10);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glTexCoord1i(0);
    glVertex2i(-1, -1);
    glTexCoord1i(1);
    glVertex2i(1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use Texture2D and 2D texture with a height of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void init()
{
unsigned char buf[ 32 * 4];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i += 4)  
    {
            buf[ i + 0] = rand() % 255;
            buf[ i + 1] = rand() % 255;
            buf[ i + 2] = rand() % 255;
            buf[ i + 3] = 255;
    }


    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // 4 or 8
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);


}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    /*
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
    */

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);


    glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);

    glLineWidth(10);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glTexCoord1i(0);
    glVertex2i(-1, -1);
    glTexCoord1i(1);
    glVertex2i(1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```